# FirebaseJobDispacher package not being added to my project after syncing gradle

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am following a Google's tutorial and I've added the following to my project:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

But when I attempt to import anything from this package, it's like it wasn't even compiled/implemented at all. I tried rebuilding and cleaning the project, erasing the line in gradle, syncing, adding it to gradle again and syncing again but nothing changes.

[image]

According to the tutorial, the `Driver` class belongs to `com.firebase.jobscheduler.Driver`, but as shown in the image, it isn't there.

Did I forget something? I saw no different action to import this package.

Comment: I exactly don't know what problem is .
But i have used `com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0` and its working.

Comment: '0.8.5' is also working at my end . Add your build.gradle.

Comment: `File > Invalidate cache & Restart`  :)

Comment: @Wizard, it worked, thank you.